# 'State' is not defined and 'handleToggle' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  Line 11:5:  'state' is not defined         no-undef  
  Line 15:5:  'handleToggle' is not defined  no-undef
```

I don't understand why it shows me these errors, please help me resolve this,  I would also appreciate an explanation

```
const Footer = () => {
    state = {
        langContent: false
    }

    handleToggle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            langContent: !this.state.langContent
        })
    }

    return (
        <FooterContainer>
            <span style={{ marginLeft: '15%', fontSize: '1.125rem' }}>
                Questions?
                <Link> Call 1-877-742-1335</Link>
                </span>
           
                {/* Language Button */}

                <div className= "lang-btn" onClick={this.handleToggle}>
                   <Icon icon={iosWorld} size={20}/>
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;English&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <Icon icon={arrowSortedDown} />
              
            </div>

            {/* Toggle Language Content */}
            {this.state.langContent && (
            <div className="lang-toggle">
                <ul>
                    <li>English</li>
                </ul>
                 <ul>
                    <li>Hindi</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             )} 
            <span style={{ marginLeft: '15%', fontSize: '0.9rem'}}>
                Netflix India
                </span>
        </FooterContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The component has been created as a functional component, which does not have state, to fix this issue you can use the `useState` hook.

```js
const Footer = () => {
    const [langContent, setLangContent] = useState(false)

    const handleToggle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLangContent(!langContent);
    }

    return (
        ... // Use existing Code
    )
}
```

If you want to continue to using class based components then you should use a class that extends `React.Component`

```js
class Footer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      langContent: false
    };
  }

render() {
... //Use existing Code
}
```

**Additional Reading**:

[React Docs for hooks-state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the syntax for using state in functional components with the syntax for using states in class components.

To use state in functional components, use it like this: (also you forgot to declare const before the function handleToggle, here you are declaring a function local variable thus const is needed. You are confusing it with declaring a method in a class)

```
const Footer = () => {

const [state, setState] = useState({ langContent: false })

const handleToggle = (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setState({
        langContent: state.langContent
    })
}

return (
    <FooterContainer>
    <span style={{ marginLeft: '15%', fontSize: '1.125rem' }}>
        Questions?
        <Link> Call 1-877-742-1335</Link>
        </span>

        {/* Language Button */}

        <div className= "lang-btn" onClick={this.handleToggle}>
            <Icon icon={iosWorld} size={20}/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;English&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <Icon icon={arrowSortedDown} />

        </div>

        {/* Toggle Language Content */}
        {state.langContent && (
            <div className="lang-toggle">
                <ul>
                    <li>English</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>Hindi</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )}
        <span style={{ marginLeft: '15%', fontSize: '0.9rem'}}>
        Netflix India
        </span>
    </FooterContainer>
)}
```

If you want to use functional component style, read more about it here: [React docs-Using the state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)